# Multiple volumes in docker.image.withRun for Jenkins pipeline

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have the next piece of Jenkins pipeline where I try to mount several docker volumes from host to container:

```
  docker.image('ubuntu:latest').withRun("-d=false --privileged -v /home/jenkins/workspace/${env.JOB_NAME}:/local " +
                    "-v /dev/vboxdrv:/dev/vboxdrv" ) {id ->
                        sh "docker logs ${id.id}"
                }
```

However, this code always fails with the next error:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot retrieve .Config.Hostname from 'docker inspect.
```

When I use single mountpoint, it runs fine without any errors.

Unfortunately, I didn't find a good doc which explains syntax of withRun method clearly.

Could you please tell what exactly I do wrong here?